# Declare enum with global names

Tags: enums, typescript

I have a Javascript function which accepts a number. Also there are some top-level constants:

```
var FOO = 1;
var BAR = 2;
```

and it only makes sense to call this function using one of these constants.

I want to create a type-safe interface for this function using enum:

```
declare enum MyType {
    FOO,
    BAR
}

interface MyClass {
    process(MyType type);
}
```

but this code outputs `MyType.FOO` in js file. I need it to output just `FOO` but still be type-safe in typescript code. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Version A
const enum _MyType {
    FOO,
    BAR
}
let FOO = _MyType.FOO;
let BAR = _MyType.BAR;
```

or

```
// Version B (if FOO and BAR come from another file)
declare const enum _MyType {
    FOO,
    BAR
}
declare let FOO: _MyType;
declare let BAR: _MyType;
```

Either way,

```
function fn(x: _MyType) { /* ... */ }

fn(FOO); // OK
fn('quack'); // Error
```